# tfs build - nuget package only projects with nuspec

Tags: .net, visual-studio, build, nuget

I have a build definition in TFS 2015

[image]

This build definition is triggered by commits to the master and should build the project, run all the tests and publish Nuget package of projects that **contain** .nuspec files.

My issue is that i want to pack **only** projects that contain .nuspec files and not just any project.

I know that i can specify "**\*.nuspec" in the path/pattern, but then i would have to explicitly specify id,title,version,desc,etc... for every nuspec and i want it to be taken from the assembly info.

Is there a way to obtain it?

Arik.

Comment: Do you mean: " know that i can specify "**\*.nuspec" in the path/pattern"?

Comment: @JeroenHeier You're right, i fixed it. Thank you.

Comment: Using csproj files has benefits (automatically finding package-dependencies for example). Probably it is more economical to do something with the names of the projects if you do not want to create a customized/custom task.

Comment: @JeroenHeier So should i keep using .csproj files in nuget packager? How do i solve my problem then?

Comment: You can change the pattern you use and/or add more NuGet packager tasks with different patterns/project files

Comment: @Arik, could you get useful information from Wendy's suggestion? If it is helpful, you could mark it as the answer, if not, please feel free to share the latest information:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .nuspec will not taken the assembly information when generated. We need to modify the id, title, version, etc... manually.

So we just need to pack the .csproj file directly, which will take the assembly information for the generated package.

Comment: But if I modify the .nuspec file, i'll have to keep maintaining it every version which is not what I hoped for, I hoped that the package information could be taken from the assembly info so I won't have to maintain it twice. I could add the nuspec creation as part of the build definition but then I would not have the ability to decide which projects I want as a nuget package and which not, all projects of that solution will be published to nuget

Comment: This is the default action for current version of NuGet when generate a nuspec file for package project. And if you could not decide which projects will be generated as a nuget package, why do you create .nuspec file for every project?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a command line task to do it manually :

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /s/b *.nuspec') do nuget pack %%~dpa%%~na.csproj -IncludeReferencedProjects -Properties Configuration=Release
```

You can also use a minimalist nuspec file (same for each projects that are supposed nugets packages) to take advantage of metadatas from AssemblyInfo :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package >
  <metadata>
    <id>$id$</id>
    <version>$version$</version>
    <title>$title$</title>
    <authors>Puresharp</authors>
    <owners>Puresharp</owners>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>$id$.$version$</description>
    <releaseNotes></releaseNotes>
    <copyright>$copyright$</copyright>
    <tags>Puresharp</tags>
  </metadata>
</package>
```